# Orientdb - extract rid from let variable

Tags: orientdb

This is an excerpt of a bigger query:

```
BEGIN
 let $project = SELECT FROM Project where id=:projectId
 let $counter = update Project INCREMENT seq=1 RETURN AFTER $current.seq where @rid=project[0].rid
COMMIT
return $project[0]
```

I am trying to use $project variable to update Project. I guess the best way to do this would be to extract @rid from this variable.

The thing that not works in above query is `@rid=project[0].rid`

I've tried other options like: `@rid=project[0].@rid`, `@rid=project.rid[0]`, `@rid=project[0]`

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting immediately the @rid:

```
BEGIN
 let $project = SELECT @rid FROM Project where id=:projectId
 let $counter = update Project INCREMENT seq=1 RETURN AFTER $current.seq where @rid=project[0].rid
COMMIT
return $project[0]
```

Hope it helps,

Regards